# How to test python module privates?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

In python 2.7, is it possible to test module privates?

After running:

```
import unittest

__private_stuff = 1 # if it would have single underscore, it would not be a problem.

class ComplexTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_internal_symbol(self):
        self.assertEqual(__private_stuff, 1)

unittest.main(__name__)
```

Result is:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_internal_symbol (__main__.ComplexTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\files\y.py", line 7, in test_internal_symbol
    self.assertEqual(__private_stuff, 1)
NameError: global name '_ComplexTestCase__private_stuff' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way arround it?

 (without modifying the code to which I want to add tests)

### Alternatives (that I would like to avoid)

One way would be to just rename the methods.

Other way would be to add additional renamed symbol `private_stuff = __private_stuff`.


But this becomes very tedious quickly.

Codebase uses these '__xyz' as public symbols (uses from other modules) and there is quite a lot of them.

Also there *always* exists '_xyz' and 'xyz' symbols.


(Trying to find the answer of "why", figured the only reasonable explanation

 is that leading underscores was used to mark "modified" as in mathematical formulas "prime" is used.
e.g. `x` and `x'` are similar, but not the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is `__private_stuff` actually defined?  Because I doubt it's defined in your test case module.  If it really is, then this will work:

```
import unittest

__private_stuff = 1 # if it would have single underscore, it would bot be a problem.

class ComplexTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_internal_symbol(self):
        private_stuff = globals()['__private_stuff']
        self.assertEqual(private_stuff, 1)

unittest.main(__name__)
```

Otherwise, if it's in some other module, this should work, although I didn't test it:

```
import unittest
import other_module

__private_stuff = 1 # if it would have single underscore, it would bot be a problem.

class ComplexTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_internal_symbol(self):
        private_stuff = getattr(other_module, '__private_stuff')
        self.assertEqual(private_stuff, 1)

unittest.main(__name__)
```

Comment: Yes, testcase will be in separate file from `__private_stuff`. (just tried to make post as short as possible as both cases raised same error)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could prevent python invoking the name mangling algorithm in your class

Use `getattr` to retrieve the value of the attribute under test (as per 1.618's answer):

```
class ComplexTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_internal_symbol(self):
        private_stuff = getattr(module_under_test, '__private_stuff')
        self.assertEqual(private_stuff, 1)
```

Write the test method outside of a class:

```
def test_internal_symbol(self):
    self.assertEqual(module_under_test.__private_stuff, 1)

class ComplexTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    test_internal_symbol = test_internal_symbol
```

Refactor the private attributes names to end with 3 underscores:

```
class ComplexTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_internal_symbol(self):
        self.assertEqual(module_under_test.__private_stuff___, 1)
```